# How to run docker commands using a docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've certain basic docker command which i run in my terminal. Now what i want is to use all the basic docker commands into one docker file and then, build that docker file.

For eg.
Consider two docker files
File - Docker1, Docker2

Docker1 contains list of commands to run

And inside Docker2 i want to build Docker1 and run it as well

Docker2:(Consider the scenario with demo code)

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER abc@gmail.com
WORKDIR /home/docker_test/
RUN docker build -t Docker1 .
RUN docker run -it Docker1
```

I want to do something like this. But it is throwing - docker: error response from daemon oci runtime create failed container_linux.go

How can I do this? Where am I going wrong

P.S - I'm new to Docker

Comment: Are you trying to run Docker inside a Docker container? Or is it automation you're after? Because for the latter maybe Docker Compose could be of help?

Comment: Do you want to run docker commands inside docker containers?

Comment: @Railslide I'm trying to just automate the process.

Comment: You can't run Docker commands from a Dockerfile (and shouldn't as a general rule try to run Docker commands from within Docker containers) but you can write an ordinary shell script on the host that runs the `docker build && docker run`.  Docker isn't the only tool you have.

Comment: If my answer answered your question, it's customary to accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example is mixing two steps, **image creation** and **running an image**, that can't be mixed that way (with a `Dockerfile`).

### Image creation

A `Dockerfile`is used to create an image. Let's take this [alpine3.8 docker file](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/c14b86580b9f86f42296050ec7564faf6b6db9be/versions/library-3.8/x86_64/Dockerfile) as a minimal example

```
FROM scratch
ADD rootfs.tar.xz /
CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

It's a base image, it's not based on another image, it starts `FROM scratch`.
Then a tar file is copied and unpacked, see [ADD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) and the shell is set as starting command, see [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd). You can build this with

```
docker build -t test_image .
```

Issued from the same folder, where the `Dockerfile` is. You will also need the `rootfs.tar.xz` in that folder, copy it from the alpine link above.

### Running a container

From that `test_image` you can now spawn a container with

```
docker run -it test_image
```

It will start up and give you the shell inside the container.

### Docker Compose

Usually there is no need to build your `images` over and over again before spawning a new `container`. But if you really need to, you can do it with `docker-compose`. [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) is intended to define and run a service stack consisting of several containers. The stack is defined in a `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  alpine_test:
    build: .
```

`build: .` takes care of building the `image` again before starting up, but usually it is sufficient to have just `image: <image_name>` and use an already existing image.

Comment: Thank you, you wrote « you can now spawn the shell inside the container », is there no way to do it within the container so you don’t have to do it with you host machine? Someone referred to your answer in my question but I’m not sure it applies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191377/docker-docker-exec-it-inside-the-dockerfile-or-yml?noredirect=1#comment117023660_66191377