# Docker: docker exec -it inside the Dockerfile or YML?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm new to docker and trying to understand how executing a PHP script works. I created an Ubuntu container and instructed it to execute a PHP script using examples like:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "set -x /usr/bin/php7.1 ./x_test/php_version.php"
CMD ["php" "./x_test/php_version.php"]
```

After executing the script nothing is shown in the logs or in the terminal.

But when I do the exact same thing after doing "attach shell" (`docker exec -it`) everything works fine and it produces output.

I tried `command: tail -F anything` in composer and adding various flags to the command like `set -x` but still nothing is happening and nothing is in the logs.

**Is there a way to put the docker exec it command inside the Dockerfile?**

When I use a similar type of command with a Java app, I get output etc but not with PHP.

[image]

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM scratch
ADD ubuntu-xenial-core-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz /
ADD selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar /

# a few minor docker-specific tweaks
# see https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap
RUN set -xe \
    \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L40-L48
    && echo '#!/bin/sh' > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d \
    && echo 'exit 101' >> /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d \
    && chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d \
    \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L54-L56
    && dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl \
    && cp -a /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d /sbin/initctl \
    && sed -i 's/^exit.*/exit 0/' /sbin/initctl \
    \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L71-L78
    && echo 'force-unsafe-io' > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/docker-apt-speedup \
    \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L85-L105
    && echo 'DPkg::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \
    && echo 'APT::Update::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \
    && echo 'Dir::Cache::pkgcache ""; Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \
    \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L109-L115
    && echo 'Acquire::Languages "none";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-no-languages \
    \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L118-L130
    && echo 'Acquire::GzipIndexes "true"; Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order:: "gz";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-gzip-indexes \
    \
# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9a9fc01af8fb5d98b8eec0740716226fadb3735c/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L134-L151
    && echo 'Apt::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant "false";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-autoremove-suggests

# delete all the apt list files since they're big and get stale quickly
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# this forces "apt-get update" in dependent images, which is also good
# (see also https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1699913)

# make systemd-detect-virt return "docker"
# See: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/aa0c34279ee40bce2f9681b496922dedbadfca19/src/basic/virt.c#L434
RUN mkdir -p /run/systemd && echo 'docker' > /run/systemd/container


# Install updates
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y software-properties-common language-pack-en-base 

# Install Java
RUN apt-get install -y default-jre


# Get the PHP library
RUN LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y \
    php7.1 \
    php7.1-pgsql \
    php-pear \
    php7.1-curl \
    php7.1-sqlite3 \
    php7.1-xml \
    php7.1-bcmath \
    php7.1-zip \
    php7.1-mbstring \
    php-xdebug \
    php-ast

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app
 
RUN /bin/bash -c "set -x /usr/bin/php7.1 ./x_test/php_version.php"
CMD ["php" "./x_test/php_version.php"]
```

Comment: This may answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52621547/how-to-run-docker-commands-using-a-docker-file

Comment: @ashok thank you it’s close but from what I understood you still have to run the commands from within the host machine inside container’s shell.

Comment: Yes @Robert Sinclair

Answer (score 0):

Total newbie mistake.. The terminal window doesn't show output returned by the script. You need additional logging commands for that.

I'm executing the following in VS Code:

```
docker compose up
```

^ this is the equivalent of executing `docker-compose  up -d --build` in terminal

This ran in detached mode which apparently doesn't output logs from the container.

So I needed to do the following to see logs from the container

```
docker containers view logs
```

^ this is the equivalent of executing `docker logs --tail` in terminal

[image]

Then I saw all the errors it was returning. Turned out I was not executing the commands in the right format.

Easy fix was to write all commands into a bash script that was then called at the end of the `Dockerfile` using the following

```
CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

start.sh looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
php script1.php
php script2.php
```

P.S: I wish docker extension in VS code had a command like "docker compose up with logs" or something so you can right away see what's happening inside the container.